# Environment variables not detected when deploying to AppFog

Tags: java, spring, appfog

It seems that when deploying my Spring app to AppFog, that the environment variables are not being detected.

I have the environment variables declared in my console:

[image: Environment Variables]

And I try to reference these from within my app code, like so:

```
<context:property-placeholder 
    location="classpath:server.common.properties,
    classpath:server.${concorde-env}.properties"/>
```

However, this generates an error:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [server.${concorde-env}.properties] cannot be opened because it does
>   not exist

This approach works fine in other (non AppFog) environments.

I logged out the properties by calling:

```
 log.info("Properties: " + System.getProperties().toString());
```

And it doesn't show those properties as available.

However, if I do a `af env <<MY_APP_NAME>>`, it shows the variables as present:

```
+--------------------------+------------------+
| Variable                 | Value            |
+--------------------------+------------------+
| concorde-env             | test             |
| spring.profiles.active   | runtime,test     |
+--------------------------+------------------+
```

What am I missing to make these variables exposed to my app at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the value like this: `System.getenv("concorde-env")` to see if the environment var can even be accessed in code.

Based on the error message `"class path resource [server.${concorde-env}.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist"` it seems like `${concorde-env}` is not even being evaluated or replaced even with empty string.

It looks like Spring has other ways of accessing env vars. Try `#{systemEnvironment['concorde-env']}` instead of `${concorde-env}`

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your answer! I faced the same problem and I fixed it with `System.getenv("MY_ENV")`. Important note! AppFog doesn't allow variables with separated dots, only with `_` or `-`. If you use dots it will return `null`.